# INET wireless interface table module parameters

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

> Module not found on path '' defined by par
>   'GPSJamming.attackhost[0].wlan[0].mgmt.interfaceTableModule' -- in
>   module (inet::ieee80211::Ieee80211MgmtSta)
>   GPSJamming.attackhost[0].wlan[0].mgmt (id=3018), during network
>   initialization

I do not know what parameter to specify for mgmt.interfaceTableModule. Is there any documentation to follow or parameters I can try? Do I put in the INI file or NED file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the parameter "interfaceTableModule" takes in a path to the module InterfaceTable. The error shows path "", which means that you did not specify a path. 
Try

```
GPSJamming.attackhost[0].wlan[0].mgmt.interfaceTableModule = default(<insert path to interface table module here>);
```